# Can a Maven plugin be created to merge 2 other plugins together?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have standardized a Maven project structure to be used amongst several developers over several projects. Part of this included removing the `<properties>` from the reactor POM and putting them in a separate file. In order to make this all work, I have to include the following 2 plugins into the reactor POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc-5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    import java.io.File;

                    String git = ".git";
                    String propertyFile = "crx.properties";
                    File f = new File(git);

                    while (!f.exists()) {
                        git = "../" + git;
                        f = new File(git);
                    }

                    project.properties[propertyFile] = f.getAbsolutePath().replace(".git", "") + propertyFile;
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${crx.properties}</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would much prefer creating my own plugin which wraps these 2 plugins so that maintenance and readability would be improved when this is used on several projects.

I know basic plugin creation/deployment and all that, but what I need to know is how, in the Mojo (plugin code), to include these plugins configured to do what they already do. If it is even possible of couse. My online research has come up short of finding an answer.

Comment: First why are you using such an old version of the [gmaven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgmaven-plugin) 1.5 is the current version. Apart from that why not supporting the [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to handle such a case? The case is only to get the root of the project in case of a multi module build and load the properties from there. If you really like to create your own plugin take a look [here|(https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor)

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for pointing out the outdated version of gmaven-plugin. The problem with using properties-maven-plugin exclusively is that 1) Using <file>${project.baseDir}/crx.properties</file> will not work for sub-modules unless there is a crx.properties file in each module 2) hard-coding a root path won't work as this is version controlled and used over several developer machines on different locations. I will look into the mojo-executor! Looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Other solution might be to create a patch for properties-maven-plugin to fit you needs.